# How capitalize fullname in vb6

Tags: vb6

hi all i have this question as bellow 
how capitalize full in one vb6 Vb6 string variable
        ‘example 
    ‘my fullname
        Dim fullname as string 
        Fullname = “abdirahman abdirisaq ali”
        Msgbox capitalize(fullname)
it prints abdirahmanAbdirisaq ali that means it skips the middle name space even if I add more spaces its same .
this is my own code and efforts it takes me at least  2 hours and still .
I tired it tired tired please save me thanks more. 
Please check my code and help me  what is type of mistakes I wrote . 
This is my code

```
                Private Function capitalize(txt As String) As String
                        txt = LTrim(txt)
                        temp_str = ""
                        Start_From = 1
                        spacing = 0
                            For i = 1 To Len(txt)

                            If i = 1 Then
                            temp_str = UCase(Left(txt, i))
                            Else
                         Start_From = Start_From + 1
                            If Mid(txt, i, 1) = " " Then
                                 Start_From = i
                                 spacing = spacing + 1
                            temp_str = temp_str & UCase(Mid(txt, Start_From + 1, 1))
                             Start_From = Start_From + 1
                            Else
                             temp_str = temp_str & LCase(Mid(txt, Start_From, 1))
                            End If
                            End If
                            Next i
                            checkName = temp_str
                End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's far simpler than that. In VB6 you should use Option Explicit to properly type your variables. That also requires you to declare them.

```
Option Explicit
Private Function capitalize(txt As String) As String
    Dim temp_str as String
    Dim Names As Variant
    Dim Index As Long 

    'Remove leading and trailing spaces
    temp_str = Trim$(txt)

    'Remove any duplicate spaces just to be sure.
    Do While Instr(temp_str, "  ") > 0
        temp_str = Replace(temp_str, "  ", " ")
    Loop

    'Create an array of the individual names, separating them by the space delimiter
    Names = Split(temp_str, " ")

    'Now put them, back together with capitalisation
    temp_str = vbnullstring
    For Index = 0 to Ubound(Names) 
        temp_str = temp_str + Ucase$(Left$(Names(Index),1)) + Mid$(Names(Index),2) + " "
    Next
    'Remove trailing space
    capitalize = Left$(temp_str, Len(temp_str) - 1)
End Function
```

That's the fairly easy part. If you are only going to handle people's names it still needs more work to handle names like MacFarland, O'Connor, etc.

Business names get more complicated with since they can have a name like "Village on the Lake Apartments" where some words are not capitalized. It's a legal business name so the capitalization is important.

Professional and business suffixes can also be problematic if everything is in lower case - like phd should be PhD, llc should be LLC, and iii, as in John Smith III, would come out Iii.

There is also a VB6 function that will capitalize the first letter of each word. It is StrConv(string,vbProperCase) but it also sets everything that is not the first letter to lower case. So PhD becomes Phd and III becomes Iii. Where as the above code does not change the trailing portion to lower case so if it is entered correctly it remains correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()

    MsgBox capitalize("abdirahman      abdirisaq       ali")
    MsgBox capitalize("abdirahman abdirisaq ali")

End Sub

Private Function capitalize(txt As String) As String

    Dim Names() As String
    Dim NewNames() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    Names = Split(txt, " ")
    j = 0
    For i = 0 To UBound(Names)
        If Names(i) <> "" Then
            Mid(Names(i), 1, 1) = UCase(Left(Names(i), 1))
            ReDim Preserve NewNames(j)
            NewNames(j) = Names(i)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    capitalize = Join(NewNames, " ")

End Function
```

Comment: Greate thanks . How to check if the first each words is string before capitalize.  Someone can write ".abdirahman .abdrisaq .ali" . ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the VB6 statement

```
Names = StrConv(Names, vbProperCase)
```

it's all you need (use your own variable instead of Names)